# Does dispersion take place in our eyes?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics

What do we see if a single ray of white light falls in to our eyes ?

Doesn't it undergo dispersion ?

Comment: Too often I think *that would be a really interesting question to answer* only to find out that the question has been asked and answered before. Damn! :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie I couldn't find any mechanism here to know whether a question has been asked before. Slag off ! :-)

Comment: With 43,573 (at the time of writing) questions on the site it's hard to check whether a new question is a duplicate. Obviously you can search, but even so it's hard to find duplicates. In this case I found the duplicate by accident. I Googled for [eye lens chromatic abberation](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eye%20lens%20chromatic%20abberation) and Google found me the question I've linked. My view would be that if you're in doubt post the question anyway.

Comment: Aside from being a dupe,  your question is ill-formed. There's no such thing as a 'single ray,' nor 'white light' . May I recommend you reword it as "does our eyeball exhibit spectral dispersion?"   Even the "what do we see" part doesn't really make sense -- do you know that a bundle of parallel rays focus to a single spot, for example?

Comment: @JohnRennie interesting that Google found you a *misspelled* duplicate :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: oh yes! Oops :-) Google is uncannily sentient sometimes.